# how to prevent javascript being aborted when my page load aborts

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, local-storage

I'm new to doing HTML and Javascript, so please bear with me.

I'm working on a web-app, that has a few different pages. When one page loads, I make a web-service call, and then write out the results to localStorage. However, some of these service calls might take a few seconds. If the user clicks on another link, the page ends loading, but my web-service calls get aborted, too.

If possible, I'd really like those web-service calls to complete, so I can write out their results to localStorage, regardless of whether the user clicked away. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can warn user before going to another page to do that use `onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```